# Pre-processing for each kafka consumer thread created with concurrency property in KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am building a kafka consumer in a spring boot application for the first time, so please direct me with the resources or sample code snippets.

My requirements are something like below:

The application should have 5-6 consumers i.e. 1 each in a thread -> This I can set using the *concurrency* attribute in `@KafkaListener` annotation

I have to create a few objects which would be used for processing messages before my kafka consumer starts, and there should be a new object for each thread because those are doing different write operations in the db -> Please suggest how can I achieve this by setting the *concurrency* attribute in `@KafkaListener`?

If I had to instantiate the threads on my own, I would have put this object initialization/pre-processing step in the run method of Runnable interface, but how to do it when using spring-kafka i.e when a new thread is initialized due to *concurrency* attribute, a method (similar to `run` method of `Runnable` interface) is called automatically that will do this pre-processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `@EventListener` method to consume `ConsumerStartedEvent`s.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#events

> `ConsumerStartingEvent` - published when a consumer thread is first started, before it starts polling.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#event-consumption